# Which function of Fragment is called from View Pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am setting the current tab in my activity from viewPager.setCurrentItem(position), this perfectly opens the desired fragment but  I want to know which function of fragment is called when setting currentItem from viewPager.I think onResume() should have been called after reading fragments lifecycle but actually onResume() is not called.

*My Activity Code:*

`viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
     actionBar = getActionBar();
     mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
     viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

*Code to select tab:*
`viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

Comment: it follows the Fragment's lifecycle.

Comment: Ya I followed the fragment lifecycle and according to me, it should have been onResume(), but when I checked onResume() it is actually not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, then when you invoke `setCurrentItem()`, the fragment's view is already cached in memory by the viewpager, so no lifecycle calls will be made on the fragment when you switch between items. (Viewpager already instantiated the fragment and went through calling its onCreate, onCreateView, onStart, onResume).

Viewpager has a method called `setOffscreenPageLimit()` which controls how many fragments will be cached in the view hierarchy. Checkout this [android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) if you wanna tune it.

If you want your fragments destroyed and re-created as you page between them, checkout [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). It's made more for that.

If you just need to react to viewpager's changes, do it in viewpager's `onPageSelected()`.